# Master List with other lists showing filtered data

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I'm having troubles with finding a solution (ootb would be best) to have a Master SP List with 3 "sub-lists", i.e. lists showing data from the Master list with a certain value in one of the columns.

The idea is to have one Master list where summary data for 3 different projects is inserted weekly (with attachments) - this list could be accessed only by people entering this data. Moreover, there would be 3 separate lists showing weekly data only for each of these projects. 

Is there an easy way of implementing something like this?

I can only think of two ways to do it:

  1) Creating the Master List and then Site Pages with filtered List Web Parts - but I don't want people to be able to access the Master List, so this is probably not good.
  2) A linked Access database with a query to update the 3 lists based on data on the Master list. This would need to be done manually each week. Also not the best option.

Many thanks!

Comment: **1)** I understand you have a list (you call it Master List) where some people have access to enter data and some other people do not have any access. Are the people entering data not supposed to view the data? **2)** You other 3 lists (you call them sub-lists) that get populated with data from the Master List on a weekly basis. What about updating the 3 sub-lists at the same time the data is entered in the Master List instead of a weekly basis?

Comment: **1)** People entering data are supposed to view it and that's fine. People from certain projects (recipients) will not have access to it. **2)** I don't have the 3 other lists yet and yes, that would be perfect if they could get updated instantly, but I don't know how to set them up to show only parts of data from the Master list (e.g. filtered by project name), so the user from project A could only see project A data and could not access the Master list with all data, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise what you want:

- A list named Master List with data for 3 projects.
- Only specific people can access the Master List to enter and view data.
- 3 separate lists, each related to one of the 3 projects.
- The data in the 3 project lists is just a copy of the some of the data from the Master List.
- Ideally, when data is added to the Master List, it is also added to the appropriate project list.

---

Here is a solution that is pretty out-of-the-box and relatively simple:

- Create the 3 project lists.
- Make sure the fields in these 3 lists are of the same type as the fields from the Master List. Since you do not copy the entire data from the Master List, then only create the necessary fields.
- Create a workflow on the Master List and set it to start when items are created.
- Presuming that the Master List contains a field that specifies which project each list item is for, then add IF statements in the workflow for each project.
- Inside the IF statements use the `Create Item` workflow action to create an item in the appropriate project list.
- Optional: Use Impersonation or the App Step in the workflow if for some reason the people who enter data into the Master List do not have access to the project lists.

Let me know if this does not make sense.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and will be easy to implement - that's what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I did not get your solution !

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA which part is confusing?

Comment: will this solution guarantee the synchronisation between the item in the original list and the master list ?

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer above. It seems simple enough, but what about when someone updates a field in the Master List? Or what about when someone deletes something from the Master List? Are you expecting to also have to delete it from the Sub List yourself? There's no event to handle that, and as such the sub-list will quickly become outdated. Unless your intention is NOT to update the items at all.

I am currently working through this problem, and am unsure as to how powerful SharePoint Designer and Workflow (or Flow) really is. As such, I am employing Access to run such updates whenever the database is opened. Looks something like this:

- Create the 4 lists (1 master, and 3 projects). All lists have the same fields except for the master list which has one more 'choice' field. This drives Access to determine which sub list the item will appear on.
- Link all lists to an access database so that updates between lists are live.
- Add queries to each table: UPDATE (if items already exist then update the fields if any changes have been made), APPEND (adds new items), and a query that will check if the ID of items in the Sub Lists exist in the Master List and delete it if not (handles deletion from master list).

Updates can only be made to the Master List, and changes are propagated over to each of the Sub Lists.

I have about zero experience with Access, so I'm pretty much going to be learning how to do this - unless someone is kind enough to help??? ;)